# RegionPlot3D Empty

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, regions

I am attempting to cut out holes in a sphere, circumscribed around a regular tetrahedron.
To do so I define some points (p1 through p4 are the vertices of a tetrahedron)

```
p0 = {0, 0, 0};
p1 = a {0, 0, Sqrt[2/3] - 1/(2 Sqrt[6])};
p2 = a {-(1/(2 Sqrt[3])), -(1/2), -(1/(2 Sqrt[6]))};
p3 = a {-(1/(2 Sqrt[3])), 1/2, -(1/(2 Sqrt[6]))};
p4 = a {1/Sqrt[3], 0, -(1/(2 Sqrt[6]))};
```

Then I cimcumsribe a sphere around that:

```
S2 = Circumsphere[{p1, p2, p3, p4}];
```

Next, create a cylinder that goes from the center of the sphere (also the center of the "tetrahedron" to a vertex of the imaginary tetrahedron:

```
C1 = Cylinder[{p0, p1}, 5];
```

Take the RegionDifference (I.e. cut out the cylinder):

```
RD1 = RegionDifference[S2, C1];
```

And plot:

```
RegionPlot3D[RD1, PlotPoints -> 30, Axes -> True]
```

**But this returns a blank graph!! Why?**

[I know the theory should work because if instead of using a sphere I use an actual tetrahedron (and points in the center of each face) it works fine. (see code below)

```
a = 10 (*Edge Length*);

p1 = a {0, 0, Sqrt[2/3] - 1/(2 Sqrt[6])};
p2 = a {-(1/(2 Sqrt[3])), -(1/2), -(1/(2 Sqrt[6]))};
p3 = a {-(1/(2 Sqrt[3])), 1/2, -(1/(2 Sqrt[6]))};
p4 = a {1/Sqrt[3], 0, -(1/(2 Sqrt[6]))};

T1 = Tetrahedron[{p1, p2, p3, p4}];

h1 = (p1 + p2 + p3)/3;
hc = (p1 + p2 + p3 + p4)/4;

C1 = Cylinder[{h1, hc}, .5];

RD1 = RegionDifference[T1, C1];

RegionPlot3D[RD1, PlotPoints -> 20, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

]
[image: Good Example]

Comment: I can demonstrate more things that work/don't work if necessary, or explain further. I tried to hit the right balance of minimal code and full explanations above.

Comment: You can get the `Sphere` from a `Circumsphere` by calling `Simplify` on it (for some reason Circumsphere documentation is online-only in 10.1 - maybe a bug). I think the problem rests with `Cylinder`. There seems to be a lot of illogical stuff and missing features like 3D Region intersections for meshes in Mathematica as well.

Comment: @Histograms What should that change, even theoretically? In practice the problem persists. What makes you think the problem is with Cylinder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with using Sphere (or Circumsphere), which are actually surfaces rather than solids. Instead use Ball:

```
a = 1;
p0 = {0, 0, 0};
p1 = a {0, 0, Sqrt[2/3] - 1/(2 Sqrt[6])};
p2 = a {-(1/(2 Sqrt[3])), -(1/2), -(1/(2 Sqrt[6]))};
p3 = a {-(1/(2 Sqrt[3])), 1/2, -(1/(2 Sqrt[6]))};
p4 = a {1/Sqrt[3], 0, -(1/(2 Sqrt[6]))};
cs = Circumsphere[{p1, p2, p3, p4}];
cyl = Cylinder[{p0, p1}, 0.05];
rd = RegionDifference[Ball[cs[[1]], cs[[2]]], cyl];
rd2 = RegionDifference[rd, Cylinder[{p0, p2}, 0.05]];
rp1 = RegionPlot3D[rd, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
   Background -> Black, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], PlotPoints -> 100]
rp2 = RegionPlot3D[rd2, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
   Background -> Black, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

Comment: What are you doing with "Ball"? It's not the smaller holes that makes it work, but the using Ball as the region. Why?

Comment: @andrewmh20 I am taking centre and radius of circumsphere and then `Ball` generates the region (x-xc)^2+(y-yc)^2+(z-zc)^2<=r^2.

Comment: But circumsphere is supposed to be usable as a region on it's own...Just like cylinder and tetrahedron. So why is ball necessary? (It also degrades the quality when compared to a pure sphere)

Comment: @andrewmh20 I suggest you run the following: `Volume[cs]`, `RegionDimension[cs]`, `RegionMeasure[cs]` and `4 Pi cs[[2]]^2`. You will notice the circumsphere is a surface and the measures and surface area coincide. Hence use of `Ball`

Comment: Alright, I see this is correct; and Tetrahedron and Cylinder are both 3 dimensional. My question is why isn't this documented better....or did I totally miss something. It seems perfectly reasonable to assume that a Sphere is 3 dimensional...

Comment: That is the [usual meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere) of Sphere. It is also documented by "Sphere represents the shell `{x | ||x - p|| = r}`".